# How to transpose eigendecomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When reading Gilbert Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra (chapter 6.4) I noticed the following transpose of an eigendecomposition:

For eigendecomposition $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ $(S\Lambda S^{-1})^{T}=(S^{-1})^T\Lambda S^T$.

Could somebody please explain how is the tranpose above justified, since I would expect it to be $(S\Lambda S^{-1})^{T}=S^T\Lambda (S^{-1})^T$ instead, following that $(AB)^T=A^TB^T$?

Comment: What is the context of this statement? Is $A$ an orthogonal projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For transpose we have $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and not the other way around.